# Unable to safely detect null value without nullable warnings

Tags: c#, .net-core, openxml, nullable

I don't quite understand the following nullable warning.

As you can see, I have part of an expression where `sheet` is not null, but `sheet.Id` may be. But why can't I used `sheet.Id.HasValue` to find out?

[image]

[image]

I also tried `sheet.Id != null`, but that gives me a different warning.

> Warning   CS8625  Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.

How can I safely determine if `sheet.Id` is not null?

#### Update

This version actually compiles without warning. But I still don't understand why the other versions give me warnings.

```
public Worksheet? GetFirstWorksheet()
{
    WorkbookPart? workbookPart = Document.WorkbookPart;
    Workbook? workbook = workbookPart?.Workbook;
    if (workbook != null)
    {
        Sheets? sheets = workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
        Sheet? sheet = sheets?.Elements<Sheet>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (sheet != null && sheet.Id?.Value != null)
            return ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart!.GetPartById(sheet.Id!)).Worksheet;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You could possible try using null conditional `if(sheet?.Id != null)`

Comment: Secondly, what is with all the nullables?

Comment: @Nkosi: That also gives me warnings CS8604 and CS8625.

Comment: @Nkosi: What do you mean? `Sheet` is part of OpenXml. The developers of that library decided what could be nullable. I'm just trying to deal with it. You should try complex development with OpenXml and nullables turned on. Fun stuff!

Comment: Hm, that's really strange. What happens if you do `if (sheet?.Id.HasValue == true)`

Comment: @derpirscher: That gives me error CS0266 because you can't use a potentially null value as the `if` condition.

Comment: @JonathanWood add the code so I can refactor it.

Comment: With non-nullable reference types you should write, e.g., `if (sheet != null && (bool)sheet?.Id.HasValue)`, otherwise you're comparing different things.

Comment: @Nkosi: Well, without handing over my entire project and the *DocumentFormat.OpenXml* package, the only reference you're missing is `Document`, which is of type `SpreadsheetDocument`.

Comment: I just meant the code in the images.

Comment: @Jimi: That doesn't eliminate the possible null reference warnings.

Comment: @Nkosi: Posted. Note that that version does compile without warnings. But I don't understand why the other syntax didn't work. Would love to see a more streamlined version of the same code that passed nullable tests.

Comment: Because you have a nullable reference type. So dereferincing it without a null-forgiving operator causes a warning.

Comment: @JonathanWood Check this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/k7d78E

Comment: @Nkosi: Set `#nullable enable` at the top of your code and try it again. You haven't reduced the amount of code needed. You've just changed the syntax so that it has six warnings with nullable enabled.

Comment: I mean, it could be something like `if (sheet != null && sheet!.Id!.HasValue) { }`, within a `#nullable enable` / `#nullable restore` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine

```cs
        if (sheet != null && sheet.Id?.Value != null)
            return ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart!.GetPartById(sheet.Id!)).Worksheet;
```

into a single equivalent expression:

```cs
         if (sheet?.Id?.HasValue == true)
            return ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart!.GetPartById(sheet.Id!)).Worksheet;
```

or

```
         if (sheet?.Id?.Value != null)
            return ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart!.GetPartById(sheet.Id!)).Worksheet;
```

I am not sure why the compiler is not smart enough to realize that the in some terms of your expression some of the fields could no longer be null.

By the way, depending on how far down the nullable chaining rabbit hole you want to go, you could rewrite the code from the images to look look something like this:

```cs
Worksheet? GetWorksheet(string name)
{
    WorkbookPart? workbookPart = Document.WorkbookPart;
    Worksheet? sheet = workbookPart?.Workbook
        .GetFirstChild<Sheets>()?.Elements<Sheet>()
        .Where(s => string.Compare(s.Name, name, true) == 0 && s.Id?.HasValue == true)
        .Select(s => ((WorksheetPart) workbookPart!.GetPartById(s.Id!)).Worksheet)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return sheet;
}
```

or

```cs
Worksheet? GetWorksheet(string name)
{
    WorkbookPart? workbookPart = Document.WorkbookPart;
    return workbookPart?.Workbook
        .GetFirstChild<Sheets>()?.Elements<Sheet>()
        .Where(s => string.Compare(s.Name, name, true) == 0 && s.Id?.HasValue == true)
        .Select(s => ((WorksheetPart) workbookPart!.GetPartById(s.Id!)).Worksheet)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the middle one. If `sheet?.Id` is null, then how is `sheet?.Id?.HasValue` not null? Also, it's interesting with the last one that I still need `!` is the return clause.

Comment: In the middle one, if `sheet?.Id` is `null` then the left hand side is `null` and cannot be equal to `true`.